# Adding checkboxes dynamically to BottomSheetDialog: setMargins() and setPadding() not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add checkboxes dynamically to a BottomSheetDialog. However, the buttons are not aligning as I want them to. Styling the checkboxes works if I style them directly on the XML, however, they don't style at all programmatically.

Here's my XML layout code with two hardcoded checkboxes:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_layout_bottom_sheet_choices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Escolha uma resposta"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancelar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm_btn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I try to add more of them programmatically:

```
LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.id_layout_bottom_sheet_choices);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
// margin-left: 10, margin-bottom: 10, like the margins in the two hardcoded xml checkboxes
params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 10);

for (int i = 0; i < answerChoices.size(); i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
    checkBox.setText(answerChoices.get(i));
    // left padding
    checkBox.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
    // i + 3 since there's already a textview and two sample checkboxes added, and i want to add the new checkbox after them and before the remaining elements
    mainLinearLayout.addView(checkBox, i + 3, params);
}
```

Here's of the output in the BottomSheetModal with that code, after the buttons are added:

[image]

As you can see, the first hardcoded checkboxes are aligned correctly, however the two other checkboxes added via coding are not. Even the checkbox select colors are different (but why???)

Here's the output that I pretend (I hardcoded the other two checkboxes just to showcase how I want the output to be after coding)

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in xml file you use `dp` unit but in code you use `pixel` unit. You must convert from dp to pixel before set margin for checkbox.

```
LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.id_layout_bottom_sheet_choices);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

// margin-left: 10, margin-bottom: 10, like the margins in the two hardcoded xml checkboxes
int margin = (int)convertDpToPixel(10F, this);
params.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, margin);

for (int i = 0; i < answerChoices.size(); i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
    checkBox.setText(answerChoices.get(i));
    // left padding
    checkBox.setPadding(margin, 0, 0, 0);
    // i + 3 since there's already a textview and two sample checkboxes added, and i want to add the new checkbox after them and before the remaining elements
    mainLinearLayout.addView(checkBox, i + 3, params);
}

// Add this method to convert dp to pixel
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    return dp * ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: i already had figured it out in the debugger where the value was 20... i then checked a website where it showed the conversions between dpis and pixels and it all made sense. thank you anyways for your help